# TortoiseHg; How to Connect to Server?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, repository

I'm starting a project with another partner of mine and have therefore resorted to using the Student Package from Kiln as a repository. I would like to get the bloody thing to work.

I've looked at the tutorials from TortoiseHg. I created a repository in my local folder in which I'm creating my code. I have committed an example change with a comment. The local repository server (me: 127.0.0.1/8000) sees the commit just fine. I just can't figure out how to push it to the server.

I tried using the Synchronize button and then going into the settings to specify my server like so:

Configure > Remote Repository Paths > Add:

```
https://MyEmail%40gmail.com:***@MyServer.kilnhg.com:8000/Repo/Repositories/Group/MyFolder
```

However, my push keeps timing out and ARGH! Getting repositories to work is such a pain for a first time xD

I would appreciate any help in getting this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like port 8000 is blocked by your firewall. Try putting an exception in your firewall program and let TortiseHg communicate via port 8000

Comment: *quickly registers and upvotes* I'll be trying this, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: You're welcome @SoulBeaver!